# Issue downloading R studio

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I am attempting to download R studio for Mac and am encountering an error when opening the application. [image] Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how to resolve this.

Comment: Looks to me you have no R installed (linux user though), have you [installed R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) first?

Comment: In addition to jay.sf's comment ... realize that RStudio != R. The R programming language is implemented and executed by applications downloaded from https://www.r-project.org/, whereas RStudio is "just" (not to diminish its value and complexity) an IDE (integrated development environment) that happens to require that "R" already be installed and available. (It also supports to some degree python, fyi.) The key here is the RStudio (not a programming language) *requires* R (the programming language) to be installed and findable in the `PATH`.